# How to model 3 glass problem to graph?

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

I'm wanting to model the question below into a graph in order to solve it:

> The barman gives you three
>   glasses whose sizes are 1000ml, 700ml, and 400ml, respectively. The 700ml and 400ml glasses start
>   out full of beer, but the 1000ml glass is initially empty. You can get unlimited free beer if you win
>   the following game:
>   Game rule: You can keep pouring beer from one glass into another, stopping only when the source
>   glass is empty or the destination glass is full. You win if there is a sequence of pourings that leaves
>   exactly 200ml in the 700ml or 400 ml glass.

I was a little unsure of how to translate this problem in a graph, my thought was that the glasses would be represented by nodes in a weighted un-directed graph where edges indicate that a glass u can be poured into a glass v and the other ways is the same therefore a walk would be a sequence of pourings that would lead to the correct solution.

However this approach of having 3 single nodes and undirected edges doesn't quite work for say dijkstras algorithm or other greedy algorithms which was what I was going to use to solve the problem, so I thought that maybe modeling the permutations of the pourings as a graph would be more suitable?

Answer (score 1):

I would model your problem as a rather huge graph with nodes $v_{ijk}$ which correspond to the state where $i \cdot 100$ ml of beer are in the 1000ml glass, $j \cdot 100$ ml of beer are in the 700ml glass, and $k \cdot 100$ ml of beer are in the 400ml glass. Of course, $i \leq 10$, $j \leq 7$, and $k \leq 4$. Two nodes $u$ and $v$ are connected by a directed edge if the state corresponding to $u$ can be transformed to the state corresponding to $v$ by a valid move.

As an example, your initial node will be $v_{0,7,4}$ and will be connected to $v_{7,0,4}$ and $v_{4,7,0}$ since you can either pour the full 700ml glass into the 1000ml glass or the 400ml glass into the 1000ml glass.

Inside this graph you have to find a path from $v_{0,7,4}$ to $v_{i,2,k}$ or $v_{i,j,2}$ for some $i \leq 10$, $j \leq 7$, and $k \leq 4$. To simplify your task you can connect all these possible end nodes to an artifitial node $v$ and look for a $v_{0,7,4}$-$v$-path instead.